# how can I see the differences in a designated file between a local branch and a remote branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-diff

How can I see the differences in a designated file between a local branch and a remote branch?

I know this command:

```
git diff <local branch> <remote-tracking branch>
```

But it gives the differences in all files between two branches while I only care about changes  of one single designated file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `git diff --help`, which shows you:

```
git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
```

So, you're almost there.  Instead of:

```
git diff <local branch> <remote-tracking branch>
```

You can use:

```
git diff <local branch> <remote-tracking branch> path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers will work, you want to get in the habit of using '--' as the file path separator.  Without the separator there can be confusion between branch names, file names and perhaps other stuff.

```
git diff <local> <remote> -- /path/to/file
```

also note that for your file path you can instead use a directory, such as /path/to/, and get only the difference for files in that directory.  You might also try 'git difftool ...' for a visual diff.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
git diff <local branch> <remote-tracking branch> /path/to/file
```